# Netbeans 8.1, Gluon Project Android Erro

Tags: netbeans

Estou com um problema e após dois dias de pesquisas e várias tentativas aqui estou eu à espera que me consigam ajudar.

Comecei a utilizar o Netbeans 8.1 para os primeiros passos em Java, tudo corria bem até que quis avançar um pouco e fiquei bastante interessado no JavaFX que com o plugin Gluon podemos criar uma aplicação para desktop e android em simultanio, com projecto Gluon não consigo correr em Android, erro:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException:
>   ANDROID_HOME not specified. Either set it as a gradle property, a
>   system environment variable or directly in your build.gradle by
>   setting the extension jfxmobile.android.androidSdk.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: ANDROID_HOME not specified.
>   Either set it as a gradle property, a system environment variable or
>   directly in your build.gradle by setting the extension
>   jfxmobile.android.androidSdk.

Já vi várias explicações para este erro mas nenhuma delas funcionou, então decidi fazer download do projecto HelloWorld da própria Gluon, e ao testar aparece exatamente o mesmo erro.

Então pensei, vou criar um projecto de raiz para android, (com o plugin nbandroid), criei um simples projecto para apresentar Bomdia, e ao executar ele corre perfeitamente no emulador...

Alguém me consegue auxiliar?
Se for necessário mais alguma informação estou à disposição.
Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Caro Sílvio,
Você já instalou o android sdk? Se não, instale. Você pode baixar através desta página:

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=pt-br

Depois, você precisa criar uma variável de ambiente chamada "ANDROID_HOME". Se você está utilizando **Windows**, vá em: Painel de controle > Sistema > Configurações avançadas do sistema > Variáveis do ambiente > Novo. Na janela que abrirá, onde está "Nome da variável" coloque "ANDROID_HOME" e em "Valor da variável" coloque o local do sdk no seu PC. Veja na imagem abaixo o meu exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Crie um projeto "default" do Gluon e teste. Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!